# if else clause in sql, automatic rebuild of indexes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am in need of a sql construct which gives the following functionality.

```
select if-expression if status='regular' else else-expression 
from table-name ;
```

This operation will be used very frequently. So, I am considering building an index for this operation.

But, I heard that indexes are not rebuilt after table is being updated. Is there a way we can have automatically rebuild indexes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The only time indexes don't update as you change the table is you actually turn them off (e.g. during bulk load operations). Normally they should ALWAYS auto-update.

Comment: (+1) Because: Required to use the same feature in production code. Is not very common, but, sometimes required by client / stackholders business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translation in SQL of your statement is:

```
select (case when status = 'regular' then <if-expression> else <else-expression> end)
from tablename;
```

An index will not help with this query, because you are not limiting the rows in any way.  An index can help when you have filters in a `where` clause, joins, and correlated subqueries (and sometimes I think with `group by`).

And as MarcB points out in a comment, MySQL (and all other databases) keep indexes up to date for insert, update, and delete operations.

Comment: Thank you very much..
But, please let me know what should I do if I want to reduce the overhead of the computing those expression every time such a query is performed

Comment: @sandilya . . . If your result set returns all the rows in the original table, then the overhead of the comparison of the `status` column is really negligible.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide a more detailed example.

There are several alternative solutions to your idea, not just the "use-the-index-luke-solution". And depends a lot on your database.

Another alternative could be using "union". In some circumstances could use too much resources, in others, may be the optimal solution, even if using too many records.

```
SELECT
  <if-expression>
FROM
  MyTable
WHERE
  (MyTable.status = 'regular')

UNION

SELECT
  <else-expression>
FROM
  MyTable
WHERE
  (MyTable.status <> 'regular')
```

And, in some circumstances, you may also add

```
SELECT
  <if-expression>
FROM
  MyTable
WHERE
  (MyTable.status = 'regular')
ORDER BY <indexed-fields-used-in-expression> 


UNION

SELECT
  <else-expression>
FROM
  MyTable
WHERE
  (MyTable.status <> 'regular')
ORDER BY <indexed-fields-used-in-expression>
```

Cheers.